# SSH doesn't bash into profile, so no permission to mkdir for vscode remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I have a weird problem and don't really know where it's coming from. I have machine A, B and C. I want to connect my VSCode to machine C with the remote-ssh extension for vscode, here's my config:

```
# Jump box
Host jump-box
  HostName machineB
  User myuser

# Target machine
Host target-box
  HostName machineC
  User myuser
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump-box
```

The machine C is a weird server used by a lot of people, when I try to connect, the connection to machine B is fine but then, the extension tries to `ssh -D -T some5XXXXport machineC bash` from B.

The last command passes fine, and I have tested it manually, however the `bash` at the end makes it run the root bash or something, because I lose my home directory and get an admin one.

So in consequence, the extension fails because it tries to `mkdir /some/admin/home/.vscode-server/bin/somecommithash: Permission Denied`. My `~`doesn't belong to me anymore when the ssh command is `bash`.

Any ideas how to overwrite or even hack the command?
Do you know why when you `ssh address bash` it breaks everything?
I also don't think the B->C ssh connection is picking any `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` nor `~/.profile` from machine C, perhaps because `~` points to another home.

Comment: Your `ssh` config doesn't indicate which user you are logging into machine C as. Also, explicitly running `bash` causes a non-login shell to be execute in place of the default login shell. You could run `bash -l`, but it would be simpler to omit the explicit command and let `ssh` do its default thing.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when I mocked the values in the config, it's obviously machineB as jump box and target is machine C. It's the same user in both machines

Comment: Just tried to `ssh -F my_config target-machine` and it worked like a charm, vscode is obviously doing something weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Added all what I need directly in the extension.js.